# Intel NUC No Sound over hdmi

Tags: intel

Hi I have just installed ubunutu on my intel nuc with a celeron n2820 processor. I am not getting any sound over hdmi. I have tried installing to pulse audio app with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried running `alsamixer`, to see if the HDMI audio device is active? I normally install and run `pavucontrol` to use Pulse Audio for configuration, not sure if that's what you did?

Comment: I have run alsammixer and here is the result http://imgbox.com/FOBwNxFg

Comment: I am not sure whether this could be an issue with the bios?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Alsa, I think you need to press F6 and select the HDMI device and make sure it's enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here is the fix I found for the nuc. Sound over HDMI works no problem after this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

Thank you for your help!