# Why is there no sound through HDMI in Lubuntu 14.04 on an Intel NUC DN2820FYKH?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, hdmi

I cannot get sound via HDMI from my NUC DN2820FYKH.

tried this but settings are not accessible from the Lububnu menu:
[lubuntu 14.04 hdmi no sound on tv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466101/lubuntu-14-04-hdmi-no-sound-on-tv)

tried this but doesn't work:
[Intel NUC No Sound over hdmi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440248/intel-nuc-no-sound-over-hdmi)

tried all other posts related to NUC/HDMI but none have a relevant/satisfactory solution.

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

I downloaded pavucontrol then accessed the app in menu>Sound & Video>PulseAudio Volume Control.

In the Configuration tab choose 'Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output'.

Note this switches off the headphone jack.

It beggars belief that this setting is so hidden in Lubuntu 14.04 and you need to download additional software to switch it on! After all HDMI has been around since about 2003! [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI ]